# CS50P PS3 outdated.py exercise - deciphering check50 frowny smiley and comment

Tags: cs50, string-conversion

So I did a sort of lazy solution of the PS3 outdated exercise by making use of a library related to working with dates and times (trying not to spoiler anything here).

Unless I am missing something, my program works as it should. However, check50 gives me a :( on one query:

:( input of " 9/8/1636 " outputs 1636-09-08
Did not find "1636-09-08" in "Date: "

So my code returns "1636-09-08" if the user inputs "9/8/1636" which seems right to me. Can anyone shed some light on how to interpret the second line of check50's output? Thanks.

Comment: Your code returns an extra space somewhere, either before the 9 or after the 1636 (Notice the spaces in the input). See [this post](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/42805/cs50p-pset3-outdated-py/42808#42808)

Comment: No, that's not it. My code does not output leading or trailing whitespace. check50 keeps complaining if I print my resulting date as "print(str(outDate).lstrip().rstrip()"

But your remark led me to the resolution, ty. check50 expects the program to remove leading and trailing whitespace from the input. The exercise does not ask for that.

So my code repromts when " 1636-09-08 " is entered. Instead, check50 expects this to go through.

Easy enough to fix that, although I find the problem statement should mention that inputs should be cleaned up for whitespace before processing further.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember the question exactly but here is my solution.

`months = [
"January",
"February",
"March",
"April",
"May",
"June",
"July",
"August",
"September",
"October",
"November",
"December"
]

## convert valid user date to output

try:
month, day, year = input("Date: ").split("/")

```
if int(month) < 10:
    month = f"0{month}"

if int(day) < 10:
    day = f"0{day}"

# split on /
print(f"{year}-{month}-{day}")
```

except:
str_date = input("Date: ")
print(str_date)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

months = {

```
"January": "1",
"February": "2",
"March": "3",
"April": "4",
"May": "5",
"June": "6",
"July": "7",
"August": "8",
"September": "9",
"October": "10",
"November": "11",
"December": "12"
```

}

def main():

```
while True:
    try:
        date = input("Date: ")
        if date[0].isdigit():
            x, y, z = date.split("/")
            x = int(x)
            y = int(y)
            z = int(z)
            if x <= 12 and y <= 31:
                print(f"{z}-{x:02}-{y:02}")
                break
        else:
            x, y, z = date.split(" ")
            if x in months:
                x = months[x]
                y = y.replace(",", "")
                print(f"{z}-{x}-{y}")
                break
    except:
        pass
```

main()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).